# Preservation of rank implies Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if the rank of $XY$ (where $Y$ is an $n\times n$ matrix) is the same as the rank of $X$ for every $m\times n$ matrix $X$, then $Y$ is invertible.

I thought I had found a counterexample:
$$
      \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
      \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=
      \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, the statement says for all $X$. How do I show that the original statement is true?

Comment: It is not a counterexample, since we must consider ${\bf every}$ $X$

Comment: Let $X=I$. Then you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ is not invertible, then there exist $v\neq 0$ s.t. $$v\perp {\rm Im}\ (Y)$$

Hence we let any row vector of $X$ to be $v$.

So $XY=0$ but ${\rm rank}\ (X)\geq 1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $Y$ is not invertible, then you can choose a nonzero vector $x$ in its left null space. Now consider the matrix product $xY$. Clearly, rank of $xY=\mathbf{0}$ is equal to zero which is less than rank of $x$ namely one.